# Hiding/obfuscating all but one legend on the x-axis

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Let's say I have a table listing employee names, certain performance aspects and scores, something like:

```
 Name | Measure | Score
 Alice| A       | 10
 Alice| B       | 5
 Alice| C       | 7
 Bob  | A       | 8
 Bob  | B       | 5
 Bob  | C       | 4
 Carol| A       | 6
 Carol| B       | 8
 Carol| C       | 7
```

This data is presented in a simple stacked column chart:

[image]

What I would like to do, is to find a way to hide all but one the x-axis legends (Name - Alice, Bob, Carol) depending on which name is selected from the slicer above.

So say Alice is selected, only her name would be displayed, the other columns would still be there but without their corresponding names, something like:

[image]

Selecting Bob would hide the other two names etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

You need to create 3 additional columns as follows.

[image]

My code for these is:

```
Alice = 
 SWITCH(TRUE(), 
 'Table'[Name] = "Alice", "Alice",
 'Table'[Name] = "Bob", UNICHAR(8203),
 'Table'[Name] = "Carol", REPT( UNICHAR(8203), 2), 
 BLANK()
 )

Bob = 
 SWITCH(TRUE(), 
 'Table'[Name] = "Alice", UNICHAR(8203),
 'Table'[Name] = "Bob", "Bob",
 'Table'[Name] = "Carol", REPT( UNICHAR(8203), 2), 
 BLANK()
 )

Carol = 
 SWITCH(TRUE(), 
 'Table'[Name] = "Alice", REPT( UNICHAR(8203), 2),
 'Table'[Name] = "Bob", UNICHAR(8203),
 'Table'[Name] = "Carol", "Carol", 
 BLANK()
 )
```

Insert a new field parameter as follows.

[image]

Create your chart as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but not sure how well it's going to scale up with a couple of thousands of names.

Comment: It won't scale up at all. To be honest, it is a very strange requirement and you might want to go back to the drawing board and think of a different approach.

Comment: it is a strange requirement but it has its reasons. The previous system, Spotfire, had this functionality and the customer really wanted to see it replicated in Power BI exactly in the same way.  In the end the customer accepted a different solution for now.  I think I can build in in Deneb but was hoping there was an obvious solution I've missed.  More flexibility with conditional formatting of the X axis would be nice.

Comment: Yes, Deneb would be an option.